# Notation to describe fetching number from set with conditions

Tags: notation

I have a candidate value which is used to determine a price from a pre-set list.

i.e.

```
candidate = 3

if (0 < candidate < 5){
    price is x
} else if (5 < candidate t){
    price is y
} ...
```

Where the limits and prices are known in advance, I can use:

$$Price =\left\{{0 < candidate < 7: $4\\7 < candidate < 90: $8\\\\etc\\}\right\}$$

However, I'm not sure how I could create a general equation which shows the above, where there could be any number of conditions greater than 0 and that a candidate should fall between them. Conditions will go from 0 to infinity such that a tariff set with a single condition will be 0 < candidate < infinity.

My attempt was:
$$Price =\left\{
{i: [0, n] \rightarrow Tarifs
\\Tarifs_ix < candidate < Tarifs_iy : Tarifs_iPrice  }
\right\}$$

The above doesn't seem right though, I'm sure there's a correct way.

Comment: Your inequalities are all "<" which means that if a candidate exactly matches the value nothing will be chosen.

Comment: the candidate will be within a certain range, like fitting into a certain bracket... if it does, that's the price that will be used. I may have the above the wrong way around or maybe I'm using the wrong notation completely. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the bounds
are strictly increasing,
and the last one is
$\infty$,
you could write

$k = \min\{i | c < bound[i]\};
p = price[k]
$

This way the min could be found
by a linear or binary search.